# Does armcc optimizes non-volatile variables with -O0?

Tags: c, volatile

```
int* Register = 0x00FF0000; // Address of micro-seconds timer
while(*Register != 0);
```

Should I declare `*Register` as `volatile` while using armcc compiler and -O0 optimization ?

In other words: Does -O0 optimization requires qualifying that sort of variables as `volatile` ? (which is probably required in -O2 optimization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you should declare `Register` as `volatile` regardless, since it is volatile.  There's no harm in marking it `volatile`, since you're depending on the compiler not optimizing away the accesses through the pointer.

```
int volatile* Register = (int*) 0x00FF0000;
```

You shouldn't depend on the compiler optimization settings to hope this gets compiled correctly.  I'd guess that forgetting to mark things `volatile` appropriately is a major reason that cranking up optimizations on embedded C code often causes things to start breaking.

Comment: Indeed, you're probably right. But as part of being a novice, I made a mistake by not paying attention to the `volatile` issue. Now, I must read again all my code which is a lot. My project test deadline is close so I don't have time. So all I got left is to hope for -O0 to save me ...

Comment: @Dor: I think you're not alone (as I implied in my last sentence). So `-O0` may well help save you, but you should really try to get those things straightened out. If not now then on the schedule for post deadline.