# C optimization breaks algorithm

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, for-loop

I am programming an algorithm that contains 4 nested for loops.  The problem is at at each level a pointer is updated.  The innermost loop only uses 1 of the pointers.  The algorithm does a complicated count.  When I include a debugging statement that logs the combination of the indexes and the results of the count I get the correct answer. When the debugging statement is omitted, the count is incorrect.  The program is compiled with the -O3 option on gcc. Why would this happen?

Comment: is there code for this?  My guess is that there's a bug in your code that the optimization brings out in some different way than without optimization.

Comment: Please post the code. While it's possible that an optimizer bug is generating incorrect code, it is also possible that an incorrect assumption in the implementation is leading to indeterminate behaviour. Without being able to see the code it is impossible to say which.

Comment: While it's possible that you've found a bug in the optimizer, it's much more likely that there's something wrong with your code (for example, relying on the value of an uninitialized variable), and putting in the debugging statement changes something so it "works". But, this is all just speculation without seeing the actual code. Try to reduce it to the smallest example that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: FWIW, Gentoo specifically recommends not using `-O3` with GCC 4.x due to "increased odds of compilation failure or unexpected program behavior".  http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gcc-optimization.xml#doc_chap2_sect3

Comment: I predict the error is on line 67 of this algorithm. For mere mortals who don't have ESP however you may want some code to show your problem.

Comment: @Ron Warholic  -- I also often use the Extended Stack Pointer to answer questions for which I don't have all of the needed information.

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: That's probably because many programs include optimizations that, strictly speaking, depend on undefined behaviour. When -O3 breaks those programs, that should not be blamed on the compiler; but it's a tad impractical.

Comment: Make sure you also use `-Wall -Werror`; you need to make your code as clean as possible before attempting to apply the optimiser, since any undefined behaviour is by definition non-deterministic.  Beyond that you'll need to post the code.

Comment: This is very common with code that violates C aliasing rules or relies on argument evaluation order. It could also be a compiler bug.

Comment: I stumbled upon this question about two years after it was raised and supposedly answered by @Matt. B/c the OP never bothered posting the code, I cannot learn anything useful from this discussion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always put your code through something like valgrind, Purify, etc, before blaming the optimizer.  Especially when blaming things related to pointers.

It's not to say the optimizer isn't broken, but more than likely, it's you.  I've worked on various C++ compilers and seen my share of seg faults that only happen with optimized code.  Quite often, people do things like forget to count the \0 when allocating space for a string, etc.  And it's just luck at that point on which pages you're allocated when the program runs with different -O settings.

Also, important questions: are you dealing with restricted pointers at all?

Answer (score 1):

Print out the assembly code generated by the compiler, with optimizations.  Compare to an assembly language listing of the code without optimizations.

The compiler may have figured out the some of the variables can be eliminated.  They were not used in the computation.  You can try to match wits with the compiler and factor out variables that are not used.

The compiler may have substituted a `for` loop with an equation.  In some cases (after removing unused variables), the loop can be replaced by a simple equation.  For example, a loop that adds 1 to a variable can be replaced by a multiplication statement.

You can tell the compiler to *let a variable be* by declaring it as `volatile`.  The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that the variable's value may be altered by means outside of the program and the compiler should not cache nor eliminate the variable.  This is a popular technique in embedded systems programming.

Comment: There was a question yesterday about optimization breaking something that should've been `volatile`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603833/does-armcc-optimizes-non-volatile-variables-with-o0

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your program somehow exploits undefined behaviour which works in your favour without optimisation, but with `-O3` optimisation it turns against you.

I had a similar experience with one my project - it works fine with `-O2` but breaks with `-O3`.  I used `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` heavily in my code and I had to make half of variables `volatile` to get it working so I decided that `-O2` is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is accessing memory that it shouldn't. Debugging symbols are famous for postponing bad news.

Is it pure C or there's any crazy thing like inline assembly?

However, run it on valgrind to check whether this might be happening. Also, did you try compiling with different optimization levels? And without debugging & optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

Without code this is difficult, but here's some things that I've seen before.

Debugging print statements often end up being the only user of a value that the compiler knows about.  Without the print statement the compiler thinks that it can do away with any operations and memory requirements that would otherwise be required to compute or store that value.

A similar thing happens when you have side effects included within the argument list of your print statement.

```
printf("%i %i\n", x, y = x - z);
```

Another type of error can be:

```
for( i = 0; i < END; i++) {
     int *a = &i;
     foo(a);
}
if (bar) {
     int * a;
     baz(a);
}
```

This code would likely have the intended result because the compiler would probably choose to store both a variables in the same location, so the second a would have the last value that the other a had.

inline functions can have some strange behavior or you somehow rely on them not being inlined (or sometimes the other way round), which is often the case for unoptimized code.

You should definitely try compiling with warnings turned up to the maximum (-Wall for gcc).
That will often tell you about the risky code.

**(edit)**
Just thought of another.

If you have more than one way to reference a variable then you can have issues that work right without optimization, but break when optimization is turned up.  There are two main ways this can happen.

The first is if a value can be changed by a signal handler or another thread.  You need to tell the compiler about that so it will know that any access to assume that the value needs to be reloaded and/or stored.  This is done by using the volatile keyword.

The second is aliasing.  This is when you create two different ways to access the same memory.  Compilers usually are quick to assume that you are aliasing with pointers, but not always.  Also, they're are optimization flags for some that tell them to be less quick to make those assumptions, as well as ways that you could fool the compiler (crazy stuff like `while (foo != bar) { foo++; } *foo = x;` not being obviously a copy of bar to foo).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is over 10 years old by now, I stumbled on a similar problem and me and a friend couldn't figure it out. Then I fixed a warning (also use `-Wall -Wextra` on GCC!) that didn't have anything with the broken pointer to do. And then it just worked, without any issues. Moral of the story? *Always make sure you don't have any warnings, no matter what kind!* Although this likely is too late for OP to see, it might at least help somebody else later on that finds themselves with a similar problem, like me.